# Запуск функции точно по минутам

Tags: python-3.x

У меня таймер запуска функции каждые две минуты. Подскажите как сделать запуск функции без учета секунд.

```
while True:
    print(datetime.now())
    minutesToSleep = 2 - datetime.now().minute % 2
    time.sleep(minutesToSleep * 60)
```

Вывод

```
2019-05-10 11:24:23.695966
2019-05-10 11:26:23.696057
```

Надо

```
2019-05-10 11:24:23.695966
2019-05-10 11:26:00
2019-05-10 11:28:00
```

Comment: Попробуйте `print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему люди так не хотят гуглить?
Подобный вопрос есть на всемирном stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463930/how-to-round-the-minute-of-a-datetime-object-python

Вкратце, надо вставить вот эту функцию.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def roundTime(dt=None, roundTo=60):
   if dt == None : dt = datetime.datetime.now()
   seconds = (dt.replace(tzinfo=None) - dt.min).seconds
   rounding = (seconds+roundTo/2) // roundTo * roundTo
   return dt + timedelta(0,rounding-seconds,-dt.microsecond)

roundTime(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Input:

> 2019-05-10 10:14:05.975842

Output:

> 2019-05-10 10:14:00